# Substitute FIND() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to substitute the `FIND` on the code below for a query in SQL Server but, the case here is that I cannot "hardcode" what I want to Find, therefore, I can't use "Like %.."

```
MID( 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345", 
    MIN(FIND(MID(Id, 5, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 1) * 16 + 
    MIN(FIND(MID(Id, 4, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 1) * 8 + 
    MIN(FIND(MID(Id, 3, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 1) * 4 + 
    MIN(FIND(MID(Id, 2, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 1) * 2 + 
    MIN(FIND(MID(Id, 1, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 1) * 1 + 1, 
    1)
```

Thanks so Much!

Comment: which rdbms? sql-server? if so you can use CHARINDEX() or PATINDEX() to get the postion of a character, you can embed other functions such as SUBSTRING(), LEFT(), RIGHT() to find he character that you then want to find.  A suggestion for re-writing this question would be to ask how to search/cut up a string in x(rdmbs) instead of how to convert your code as the former requires knowledge of 1 system the later 2 systems both of which you do not specify in your question.

Comment: Hey Matt thanks for the updates and you are absolutely right on modifying the question.  Although you've pointed me to the right direction in using CHARINDEX() in combination with SUBSTRING() so, it works like this:    SUBSTRING( 
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345', 
    CASE WHEN  ((CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(Id, 5, 1), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") >1) THEN 16 ELSE 0 END +  ..and repeat for the others   Thanks for the help!